# Unable to load image from assets when more than 1 level deep (symlink folder)

Tags: angular, assets

In a template such as follows:

```
<figure>
    <img src="./assets/rsc/stage/germination/1-GrainGermeRadicule.thumb.jpg">
    <figcaption>
        Figure 1 : Germination
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I cannot have the image loaded.

Straight from the browser URL input field, I try to read the image as `localhost:4201/assets/rsc/stage/cornStage1.jpg` but the app loads itself instead (I mean http redirects).

I noticed that there's no problem when I try `localhost:4201/assets/rsc/field.jpg` for exemple (one level upper).

Note that rsc is a symlink from the local machine.

Comment: what do you mean by  'rsc is a symlink from the local machine.';

Comment: I did a ln -s rsc to share the rsc folder among several apps on my Mac.